# Passing value into textbox

Tags: c#, silverlight, textbox, childwindow

I am using Silverlight, and passing a value into a textbox in a childwindow,

the `textBox1_TextChanged` event should fire a webservice call that should populate a listbox on the childwindow, however for some reason when the child window loads, the text box has the value passed into it as desired, but for some reason the `TextChanged` event is not firing?

Is there any specific reason for this?

Here is the change event -

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebService.Service1SoapClient client = new WebService.Service1SoapClient();
        client.PRSHListCompleted += new EventHandler<PRSHListCompletedEventArgs>(client_PRSHListCompleted);
        client.PRSHListAsync(System.Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text));

        textBox2.Text = "OK"; //I did this to test if I was getting to the event and it failed.
    }
```

I pass in `textBox1.Text` from the parent window here-

```
Settings set = new Settings();
set.textBox1.Text = System.Convert.ToString(PRSID);

set.Show();
```

Where `set` is the child window.

This is the XAML for the text box -

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,13,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged" />
```

Comment: could you give us the pieces of code where you are making the event subscription?

Comment: Could you paste some code, primarily how the event is hooked up and how the value is passed to the text box.

Comment: ok, that is great now we could see event handler and text change code, but what about the code where you are making the event subscription?

Comment: Could you explain event subscription please?

Comment: set.textBox1 += textBox1_TextChanged; (in C# code) or <TextBox ... TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged" ... /> (in XAML)

Comment: Im not sure but there is an update?

Comment: yep, everything looks good. "TextChanged event is not firing" - try to set the brakepoint in the very beginning of the textBox1_TextChanged method and let us know if it fires

Comment: I've suggested this (my comment above), as you may have an exception in the code before 'textBox2.Text = "OK"'

Comment: Yep I have tried putting a break point there, the changed event does not fire, suggesting that it isn't being invoked? Does this mean that the text isn't changing? Even though I can see the value on the child window? Its odd.

Comment: ohh, I've been able to reproduce it. I'll let you know, if I could figure out why the behaviour is so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `textBox1.Text` right after the `Settings.Loaded` event is fired and all XAML event subscriptions are made.

So try this one:

```
Settings set = new Settings();
set.Loaded += (o, args) =>
{
    //set.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    //{
    set.textBox1.Text = System.Convert.ToString(PRSID);
    //});
};

set.Show();
```

Comment: Its odd, this worked once, but trying it again it fails? If I manually delete and then type in the PRSID once the form has loaded, this fires the textBox-Changed event and the value updates the lstbox. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've updated my code. if you uncomment the new code, everything should be fine, _but_ I'm still not sure why it is not stable without the new code. I'll try to figure out what is the problem and , if I find something, I'll let you know

Comment: You got it! If I may ask for an explanation of why this method works please? I take it is force clearing the form then updating? Really appreciate.

Comment: I am no trying to use the values in the textBox in the initialise component section of the set child window, however it is saying they are null? How can I solve this?

Comment: sorry, I don't get it. could you please throw me a piece of code?